# How to inject dependency MassTransit Consumer in windsor container

Tags: dependency-injection, castle-windsor, ioc-container, masstransit

How to use dependency injection in consumer class. I get error message as "The type 'Esb.Masstransit.RabbitMq.Application.IEventConsumerService' cannot be used as type parameter 'TConsumer' in the generic type or method 'MassTransit.ConsumerExtensions.Consumer(MassTransit.IReceiveEndpointConfigurator, System.Action<MassTransit.ConsumeConfigurators.IConsumerConfigurator>)'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'Esb.Masstransit.RabbitMq.Application.IEventConsumerService' to 'MassTransit.IConsumer'"

This is container class

```
container.Register(Component.For<IEventConsumerService>().ImplementedBy<EventConsumerService>().LifestyleSingleton());
container.Register(Component.For<ICommandConsumerService>().ImplementedBy<CommandConsumerService>().LifestyleSingleton());

var busControl = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(rabbit =>
        {
            var host = rabbit.Host(new Uri(rabbitMqHost), settings =>
            {
                settings.Password(rabbitMqUserName);
                settings.Username(rabbitMqPassword); 
            }); 

            rabbit.ReceiveEndpoint(host, eventQueue1, e =>
            {
                e.BindMessageExchanges = false; 
               e.Consumer<EventConsumerService>(); // I getting error here
                e.Bind(typeof(IPublishMessage).FullName.Split('.').LastOrDefault(), x =>
                {
                    x.RoutingKey = "1";
                    x.ExchangeType = ExchangeType.Direct;
                });
            }); 
        }); 
        container.Register(Component.For<IBus, IBusControl>().Instance(busControl));
```

This is Consumer class

```
public class EventConsumerService : BaseLogger, IEventConsumerService, IConsumer<IPublishMessage>
{
    private readonly ICommandConsumerService _service;

    public EventConsumerService(ICommandConsumerService service)
    {
        _service = service;
    }

    public Task Consume(ConsumeContext<IPublishMessage> context)
    {
        try
        { 
            Console.WriteLine("In event consumer " + context.MessageId + " _" + context.Message.MessageId + ", " + context.Message.Message + " " + context.Message.CreationDate);
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
           Logger.Error("EventConsumerService", ex);
        }
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You should use the container integration package, [MassTransit.CastleWindsor](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MassTransit.CastleWindsor/) and configure your container as shown in the [documentation](https://masstransit-project.com/usage/containers/castlewindsor.html).

> Also, consumers should be registered as concrete types, not interfaces.

Based upon your example:

```
var container = new WindsorContainer();
container.AddMassTransit(x =>
{
    x.AddConsumer<EventConsumerService>();

    x.UsingRabbitMq(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.Host(new Uri(rabbitMqHost), settings =>
        {
            settings.Password(rabbitMqUserName);
            settings.Username(rabbitMqPassword); 
        }); 

        cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(eventQueue1, ec =>
        {
            ec.ConfigureConsumeTopology = false; 
            ec.Bind(typeof(IPublishMessage).FullName.Split('.').LastOrDefault(), b =>
            {
                b.RoutingKey = "1";
                b.ExchangeType = ExchangeType.Direct;
            });

            ec.ConfigureConsumer<EventConsumerService>(context);
        });
    });
});
```

> Consumers should not be singleton, they should be scoped. The code above will register the consumer in the container for you.